# How do I fix "Grub Rescue"? Uninstallation?

Tags: grub2

I am currently dual-booting windows 7 and Ubuntu. I am about to sell my computer so I was following a tutorial on how to uninstall Ubuntu. I had deleted my partitions like the tutorial 
said and now I get this:

error  :  no such partition
grub rescue>_

I am now looking for help on

1. Getting out of this "grub rescue"
2. Uninstalling Ubuntu and/or factory reset

Notes
-Newbie
- No windows disks
-I have spare CDs

Comment: Try boot-repair-disk ,it will help you to boot into windows.

Answer (score 13):

(From within rescue mode)

Command: *ls*

It will list all your drives and partitions, like:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

If you don't know your Ubuntu boot partition, check them one by one:

```
ls (hd0,msdos2)/
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
```

When you hit the right one, you'll get a line mentioning "lost+found" and so on.

Assuming `(hd0,msdos2)` is the right partition:

```
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,2)
insmod normal
normal
```

Now you'll be able to boot into Ubuntu. Once you do, execute the following commands:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Voila.

Comment: He deleted the ubuntu partitions, so I guess there is no ubuntu to boot to

Comment: Yes he deleted the ubuntu partition and try to recover windows partition.

Comment: A Win 7 recovery DVD can be written from any Win 7 machine. Boot from recovery DVD, choose to recover win loader from the graphic menu, or choose to enter command line and execute *bootrec /fixmbr* and *bootrec /fixboot*.

Answer (score 2):

You could do either of two things:

1. Use a Windows 7 installation CD, boot it, and search for the repair option. After that you will get many options; then search for 'command prompt'. Type the following commands into a command prompt one-by-one and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   - `bootrec.exe/fixmbr`
   - `bootrec.exe/fixboot`
     Thats it done. Or watch [this YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JFrmDubY5M).
2. If you have any Linux installation CD/DVD or USB pendrive then live boot it and follow the steps shown on the page *[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)*. You will get the boot menu back.