# Ubuntu starts with a grub command line instead of a GUI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I already had Windows 10 on my computer, and I wanted to install Ubuntu on my computer as a dual boot. I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS version, and use Rufus to create a bootable USB.

I looked up some tutorials online, and I turned off the fast start option in windows, booted from my USB and install Ubuntu, using the default option. It shows Ubuntu was successfully installed.

In order to boot from Ubuntu, I downloaded the **EasyBCD** and added a new entry for Linux, the type was **GRUB 2**.

And then I rebooted, chose to boot from Ubuntu, and it started with a grub command line instead of GUI, it shows:

```
[ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
completions of a device/filename. ]

grub>
```

I looked it up in Google and it said that there's something wrong with my bootloader, and I should type "ls" in the grub command line to look up the storage in my computer, however, when I typed "ls", the following shows:

```
Error 14: Filesystem compatibility error, cannot read the whole file.
```

I don't know if there is any solution to it. And if I change the EacyBCD type to "GRUB (Legacy)", the screen will only be left with a flashing cursor when booting.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Windows 10 is Installed on your system. Later you installed Ubuntu along side windows. That's it. You should not go for EasyBCD. Ubuntu will show you options with GRUB to choose between Ubuntu and Windows. Further Easy BCD will work only for MBR Partitioning type. I think yours might be GPT.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/883992/stuck-at-grub-command-line/884024; https://askubuntu.com/questions/373385/how-do-i-fix-grub-rescue-uninstallation

Comment: I've already checked my computer, and it's MBR Partitioning type... The tutorials online said the EasyBCD only makes it easier for me to choose one OS to boot from. And if I delete the EasyBCD, I can't find a way to boot from Ubuntu.

Comment: I've already tried to type `ls` in the grub command and it turned out error 14, as I've said above.

Comment: Unfortunately, EasyBCD is designed for Windows primarily. For Ubuntu, you should try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If it does not solve your problem automatically, please report the URL it gives.