# Ubuntu 16.04.5 freeze after suspend | Black Screen

Tags: 16.04, suspend, crash

I recently switched back to **ubuntu 16.04.5** from 18.04 due to bugs. And I felt it was the most stable version (no bugs). But a new problem occured in my laptop. Whenever my laptop suspends (**long period [2-3 hours]**) and when I try to wake, it crashes. **Black Screen** and I've no other choice except to reboot. I usually suspend my laptop by **closing the lid**.

**Please Help**

[image: My Power]

[image: My Grub]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as I know, it was due to multiple linux(ubuntu) distro in my system. My GRUB was in Ubuntu 18.04 and the problem arose in Ubuntu 16.04.5.

I figured out simply by removing ubuntu 18.04 as my primary OS is **16.04.5** and `sudo update-grub`.

> **Note:** removing **18.04** and **updating grub** might encounter some problem like **Grub Rescue** on Boot. 
>   Read this: [How do I fix "Grub Rescue"? Uninstallation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373385/how-do-i-fix-grub-rescue-uninstallation)